# Find the Inverse Laplace Transform:

Tags: partial-fractions, inverse-laplace

Please help me in finding Inverse Laplace transform of :
$$
\frac{a(s^{2}-a^{2})}{s^4+4a^{4}}
$$

I have tried id by following ways but need help in further approach

$$
splitting\ \ \ s^4+4a^4=(s^2+2as+2a^2)(s^2-2as+2a^2)\\and\\tried\ using\ partial\ fractions\ to\ solve\ the\ problem
$$

But was not able to solve please HELP!

Comment: Where did you get stuck exactly?

Comment: After breaking it using partial fractions i was unable to further arrange it algebraically to apply inv laplace proprties

Comment: Maybe consider the roots $s_n = e^{i\pi {2n+1 \over 4}} a$ for $n=0,...,3$?

Comment: @copper.hat I am unable to understand please elaborate

Comment: Sorry, I had a small mistake. Maybe consider the roots of $s^4+4a^4$ which are $s_n = \sqrt{2}e^{i\pi {2n+1 \over 4}} a$ for $n=0,...,3$.

Comment: $s^2+2as+2a^2 = (s+a)^2+a^2$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint.

$$
\frac{1}{((s+a)^2+a^2)((s-a)^2+a^2)} = \frac{c_1+c_2s}{(s+a)^2+a^2}+\frac{c_3+c_4s}{(s-a)^2+a^2}
$$

then as

$$
\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left(\frac{\mu_1+\mu_2 s}{(s\pm a)^2+a^2}\right) = \frac{e^{\mp a t} \left(\left(\mu _1\mp a \mu _2\right) \sin (a t)+a \mu _2 \cos (a t)\right)}{a}
$$

and

$$
s^n \hat f(s)\leftrightarrow\frac{d^n}{dt^n}f(t)
$$

we are done.